# Kendo Date Picker turning blank when 31/12/2099 is entered

Tags: c#, jquery, json, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I have a `kendo` date picker declared as below:

```
  @Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m=> m.BlHeader.BlDt)
               .Name("BlDt")
               .Format(dateFormat)
               .Culture(@agentculture)
               .HtmlAttributes(new {  id = "BlDt", style = "width:110px;" })
```

If I enter `31/12/2099` and save the data, the Date gets saved in the backend but the date-picker goes blank.

Below logic is written in `jquery` to reload the date picker with the date returned in `JSON` format after I save the data.

```
$('#BlDt').data("kendoDatePicker").value(HeaderDetails.BlDt);
```

The **HeaderDetails.BlDt** has the value `"/Date(4102358400000)/"`

> **Please Note:** When I am selecting any date before 31/12/2099
>   (i.e.31st December 2099) from the date picker calendar and save the
>   data, everything works fine.

Comment: Define the range for Date using Max and Min function, it might help!

Comment: here is a dojo showing you how to set the max date https://dojo.telerik.com/EQIxaT (this should work with dates up to 2110)